# How does displacement current relates to capacitive coupling?

Tags: electromagnetism, capacitance, maxwell-equations

Im reading make: electronics, and I have investigated a little bit about displacement current and how a change in electric flux can create a magnetic field in a vacuum. A can understand that, however there is one effect which I don't comprehend the physics behind it.

The effect that I'm talking about can be resumed in the next quote from the book: "A sudden change in voltage on one plate in a capacitor induces an equal change in voltage on the other plate, as if is reacting in sympathy".

[image]
*An image from the book showing the voltages in both plates of the capacitor in respect to time.*

**My theory:** So my theory is that since there is a current displacement there is also a change in magnetic flux, and this change in magnetic flux can generate a similar voltage on the other plate, since the plate has thickness and thus inside the plate there is an area that is perpendicular to the direction of the magnetic field, which will lead to a magnetic flux, and if you change the magnetic flux a voltage is created (according to Lens and Faraday).

However, I don't know if this is right, and at the same time trying to find information on the internet about it is impossible. If anybody has an answer I will be delighted.